# Android : AlarmManager not start

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I must create an AlarmManager that repeating every seconds, I use this code

```
Intent in = new Intent(context,Tempo_Indietro.class);
in.putExtra("id_widget", appWidgetIds[i]);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000, pi);
```

but it don't start...why ??

Answer (score 0):

To start a Scheduled Activity: you can use like:

Step1: Setting for AlarmManager

```
    Intent intent =new Intent(context,AlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManger.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000, pi);
```

Step2: creating a BroadcastReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 //override onReceive(Context, Intent) method
 @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
 {
 //.........
    Intent i = new Intent(context,Tempo_Indietro.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
//..........  
 }
```

}

Note: Don’t forget to include the newly created activity, receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Ok but why it dpn't start with getActivity ?

Comment: Because Using a BroadcastReceiver is the most common scenario. It is required for _WAKEUP alarms, if you want the device to reliably wake up when the alarm goes off. Detail, you can see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641141/start-activity-using-alarmmanager-without-broadcastreceiver

Comment: Yes I know but into other application I have used getActivity and it worked well...perhaps into widgetprovider I can not use AlarmManager with getActivity?